# How do I get a Wallet address?

Tags: address

New to this (obvious)
Using armory.
To send/receive BC's I need and address for the wallet.
How do I get this address?
Simple question and have searched but no direct answer??

Thanks

Comment: There should be a receive bitcoins button. Also welcome to Bitcoin SE, the question you asked could be figured out through a google search and this really isn't that useful of a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Electrum a very user friendly wallet, alternatively to get you started off you could simply set up a web wallet somewhere like blockchain.info.

I suggest having a look over the bitcoin.org page here:

[Choosing Your First Wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)

Answer (score 0):

In the top right corner there is a button that says "Create Wallet" and "Import or restore wallet". Click "create Wallet". Enter a wallet name and a description. You can then enter a passphrase for the wallet. You should right this down too in a safe spot.

To view your bitcoin address open up "Receive Bitcoins" or "Send Bitcoins"

Comment: Now the question is how do I uninstall Armory.